# Не загружается css после переноса домена joomla

Tags: joomla, css

Перенес Joomlu в поддомен. Перестали подгружаться стили (css).
Хотя при просмотре "кода страницы", пути указаны верно.

В "конфиге" подправил значения.

В режиме "Отладчика" ошибок нет.

Сам сайт работает, но без оформления. Админка так-же полностью функционирует, но без оформления. Словно css вообще не используется.

Подскажите, куда копать. Возможно ли, что шаблон слетел? Хотя и там все перепроверил.

UPD: Многие картинки перестали отображаться. Но при переходе до изображения, открываются. Они есть в каталогах, но возможно из-за того, что также пути к ним указаны в css, не открываются. Третий день голову ломаю.

Comment: Естественно чистил кэш и проверял в других браузерах и на других устройствах.

Comment: а сами css файлы по новому url в браузере открываются? Содержимое их верно?

Comment: Хм... При клике на ссылку css файла редиректит на главную страницу. Похоже в одном из подключаемых ранее скриптов "лишняя" кавычка и дальнейший контент "комментитмся". Щас еще покопаюсь.

Comment: В консоли: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: Проверьте .htaccess и настроенные редиректы. У вас ответ в консоли дан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, [VenZell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13336/venzell), оказался прав. Проблема была в **.htaccess**, который не был настроен на работу в домене третьего уровня.

Спасибо за помощь!